# Create multiple div and assign a name on each div with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a new div with a form inside every time a user click on another div (named: create new group). With the form the user can put a title on the div. Till now I can create all the div with the forms inside but I can't put the name on them.

This is the code I wrote (here's the link for jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o03uzLa7/14/)

```js
var counterdiv = 0;
var counterform = 0;
var counterp = 0;
var counterinput = 0;
var counterbutton = 0;

$("#add").click(function() {

  $('<div/>', {
    id: 'group' + (++counterdiv),
    "class": "group"
  }).appendTo('.modal-icons');

  $('<form/>', {
    id: "name-form" + (++counterform),
    'class': "name-form"
  }).appendTo('#group' + counterdiv);

  $('<p/>', {
    id: 'nomegruppo' + (++counterp),
  }).appendTo('#group' + counterdiv);

  $('<input/>', {
    id: 'fname' + (++counterinput),
    "type": "text"
  }).appendTo('#group' + counterdiv);

  $('<button/>', {
    id: 'button' + (++counterbutton),
    type: "submit",
    text: "submit"
  }).appendTo('#group' + counterdiv);


});



var groupname = localStorage.getItem('receivedName');
if (groupname == null) {
  groupname = "inserisci nome";
}

function changeName() {
  groupname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  saveName();
  getGreeting();
}

function saveName() {
  localStorage.setItem('receivedName', groupname);
}

document.getElementById("name-form").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  changeName();
});

function getGreeting() {
  document.getElementById("nomegruppo").innerHTML = `${groupname}`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-icons">
  <div class="flex-container" id="add">
    <p style="margin-left: 15px"> Create New Group </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create `name` the same way you create `id`. Does that solve your problem? If not; the problem needs a more detailed explanation

Comment: Also don't see way you need so many counter variables

Comment: @charlietfl Right! I already deleted all the counter and used the counterdiv as well. I didn't solve the name problem

Comment: You've got an odd mixture of jQuery and plain old DOM manipulation. It's easier for later readers if you stick with one or the other throughout a code base. That's just my opinion though.